# How do I load an image from my project folder inside a JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build a website and I currently am using a data.js file to be the source of images and links in one of my components. The file structure looks like this right now.

[image]

And my data.js file looks something like this:

```
export const products = [
  {
    id: 1,
    img: "",
    link: "http://lama.dev",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    img: "",
    link: "http://lama.dev",
  },
];
```

I wish to use the images under my 'img' folder to be inside the `img: "xxx"` part but I am unsure how. Is this even possible?

Not sure if this is needed but this is how I intend to use my data.js file:

```
import "./product.css";

const Product = ({ img, link }) => {
  return (
    <div className="p">
      <div className="p-browser">
        <div className="p-circle"></div>
        <div className="p-circle"></div>
        <div className="p-circle"></div>
      </div>
      <a href={link} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
        <img src={img} alt="" className="p-img" />
      </a>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Product;
```

Comment: Do you want it to be refreshed when you upload a new file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can import your image from your img folder like this.

```
import FirstImg from "./img/pexels-cátia-matos-1072179.jpg";
```

and you can use like this in same file

```
export const products = [
  {
    id: 1,
    img: FirstImg,
    link: "http://lama.dev"
  }
];
```

or

You can change your img folder location to public

[Folder structer image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnsAB.png)

**public/img**

and you can use like this

```
export const products = [
  {
    id: 1,
    img: "./img/470a19a36904fe200610cc1f41eb00d9.jpg",
    link: "http://lama.dev"
  }
];
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked and it was what I was looking for. Have a nice weekend.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your data.js

```
import figma from './me.jpg'
export const products = [
  {
    id: 1,
    img: figma,
    link: "http://lama.dev",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    img: "",
    link: "http://lama.dev",
  },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move your images folder under public directory. Otherwise all those images would be bundled when you create your react app.

You can then make your data.js to

```
const products = [
  {
    id: 1,
    img: '/img/image.jpg',
    link: 'http://file/'
  }

]

export default products
```

Answer (score 0):

use `require` method in js

```
const products = [
  {
    id: 1,
    img: require('/img/image.jpg'),
    link: 'http://file/'
  }

]

export default products
```